# Nested resources

Tags: yii

I'm stuck with one approach and use Yii framework.

My site has 4 sections (groups, pages, events, photos) and some may contain other, ie, I could have:

```
/ pages/1/groups/4
/ pages/1/groups/4/events/5
/ pages/1/groups/4/events/5/photos
/ groups/6/events/7/photos
/ groups/6/photos
```

The models are 4 (Group, Page, Photo, Event) and are linked by a field called container_guid. How I can reuse the controllers and views of each section?

Comment: Why would you like to reuse controllers? IF they are different data types they should have separate controllers/views in my opinion. From the other hand, you may want to serve all content from one controller with multiple methods. As usually, everything depends on your current project. Please provide more details.

Comment: I want to reuse the controller that manages each model, eg / pages/1/groups/4/events/5 -> PageGroupEventController and / groups/6/events/7 -> GroupEventController, and both controllers have the same methods.

Answer (score 0):

**Reusing views:**

```
$this->render('/controller_id/view_id')
```

This way you can call another controller's views..

Though I heard this feature was not there in old versions..

**Reusing Controllers:**

you can call forward function in your controller to forward request to another controller's action...

This way you can delegate task to other controller's action..Read Details of this function

[Yii Documentation For Forward Function..](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#forward-detail)